# Time series compression with interpolation

Tags: algorithm, time-series, signal-processing, interpolation

I basically have an algorithm, but it is really slow. Since my algorithm/problem is so simple, I expect, that this may exist somewhere (in fast) and there might also be a name for this. And before I start developing a faster version of my algorithm, I first try to ask here (I don't want to reinvent things).

The problem is simple: I have a time series from an experiment, which is quite large (~5 GB). The thing is, that most of the data points are placed on a line, e.g.

(t=0.0, y=0.0), ... , (t=1.0, y=0.5), ... , (t=2.0, y=1.0)

This could obviously be simplified by interpolating the first and the last point with a straight line. In principle, I can test, if the points between an interval can be approximated by a straight line, within some tolerance (I don't need lossless compression) and throw away the points in between.

My current algorithm works as follows:

1. I have points within an interval [a,b] and I create a linear interpolation between the first and the last point (let's call this interpolation f).
2. Then, I compute the error Abs(f(t) - y) at each time series point and select the point, with the largest error (let's cal this point tmax).
3. I split the interval [a,b] -> [a, tmax], [tmax, b]
4. Repeat my algorithm on the sub intervals, until a tolerance is reached, or the interval contains only one or 2 points. Return the interval boundaries.

This algorithm works surprisingly well in approximating a signal, but it is really slow and as already said, I believe that there exist already something, which does the same thing or solves my problem.

Thanks for the help, if anything is unclear, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: What do you call "really slow" ? One minute or one hour ?

Comment: You might consider computing the slopes between successive points and group by similar slopes, as a preliminary compression step or as the main algorithm.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm not an expert in computing the complexity of an algorithm, but a fried told me that this is O(n^2) and if n is very large it takes some second (I'm doing this multiple times) on multiple files. It is difficult to estimate the time since it varies. I need something, which scales at least linear in n. The idea with grouping similar slopes sounds nice, I wait for a few other answers and then think, how I might implement that.

Comment: Are the y-values of adjacent points similar? Would you expect the points close to your highest error point to also have high errors?

Comment: @Dave What do you mean by similar? Yes, the points of the experiment should be “continuous” (continuos meaning: not jumping around), therefore if $y_i$ has a large error, $y_{i+1}$ should also have a large error (as well as $y_{i-1}$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want the Swinging Door compression algorithm.  It basically works by using the mental image of a pair of doors to quickly absorb points into a range that can be approximated by a single straight line.  It shows up a lot for processing time series in industrial automation.  Which is a domain where people wind up collecting a lot of data, very quickly, and needing to summarize it on the fly before doing other calculations.

I won't explain it because there are plenty of good explanations out there, with source code.  Here a links to a couple.

[Swinging Door in PostgreSQL](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/using-the-swinging-door-trending-algorithm-in-postgresql_595129)

[Swinging Door in Python](https://pypi.org/project/swinging-door/)

Comment: A follow up question: do such things also exist for 2 dimensions and using a Bilinear interpolation?